# Server throws ArgumentNullException only to Android os but not to web or iOS

Tags: c#, android, ios, backend, claims-based-identity

Right now I am working on a project as a backend developer with C#. I worked on the API that will be called by web, iOS, and Android. I have this method that is supposed to create a record for me and keep track of it, and it asks the user to input a date to record it. Now the issue is, I've tested this method thoroughly using Postman and debugging point, and it's working perfectly. However, the problem came from the android team as they keep getting a ArgumentNullException on a DateTimeParse.Parse. 
What's getting on my nerves is that it's only Android that has this issue, iOS works perfectly as well as web browsers, even when I took the exact same request from Android, along with the same credentials, it still didn't work.
Any idea where this exception is coming from? I lost hope after duplicating several requests that failed on Android but worked perfectly on my device (Localhost as well as live website, both works.)

Actually, after more debugging, I figured out where the error is, but now why it's occurring or how to fix it. Within the method call, there's a date parser that is parsing the join date claim of the user, the issue is with that claim. The thing is this issue now occurs to newly registered users through both iOS and Android and also live website, but nothing of this sort happens when I'm testing it locally, even when I'm using the credentials of a user that was created with iOS or Android.

Comment: The value that is being passed into the DateTime.Parse method is null.

Answer (score 0):

If your service sends correct response, line in JSON format, you must check you fill the value for them, so they don't get exception. If you did and the Android team get exception still, it might be problem with the format you send. Check if you send correct data like, if you send timestamp, they should get it in `long` data type, then format it accordingly as they wish.

Comment: Please refer to the edit, I explained more about the issue